# sending an SMS text message

Tags: asp.net, mobile, sms

How can I send an SMS text message from my cellphone and have it received and processed on my asp.net website? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you willing to spend any money? If so, how much?

Comment: So you really want to "receive an SMS message" programmatically, right? I assume you know how to send one from your phone.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to achieve with your application.

For a more robust solution you would need to use an SMS Gateway provider. I would recommend someone like Clickatell http://www.clickatell.com/products/two_way.php. They have a simple API you can integrate with to send and receive messages via your application.

The drawback here is that you'll need to pay for setup as well as rent a virtual mobile number which will be used for receiving messages.